# jQuery help: How can i select tr td nth row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
table#id_table_comments tr td {
    /*background: #fff;*/
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 6px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
table#id_table_comments tr:nth-child(2n) td {
    /*background: #f5f5f5;*/
    background: #fff;
}
.classTableRow{
    background-color: #9999CC;
    border: 1px solid gray; 
}



$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('classTableRow');
    })

    $("td").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('classTableRow');
    })
});
```

But the jQuery is not working for the nth row(even row) .

What should i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table#id_table_comments tr:nth-child(2n) td` is more specific than `.classTableRow`, so its background wins.
Add `!important` to the `.classTableRow` background to force it to override the other selector.

Also, you should use `:hover` instead of using jQuery to add a class.

Comment: What's the problem with mouseover and mouseout ? why should i use :hover ?

Comment: They're slower.  It's always preferable to use CSS rather than Javascript.  They're also wrong (they bubble); if you really want to use Javascript, you should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: What's the difference between mouseover/mouseout and mouseenter/mouseleave ?

Comment: isn't `.hover(function(){},function(){})` better than two separate howerin/hoverout functions?

Comment: @Tum: Yes.  However, you should use a CSS `:hover` selector instead.

Comment: @SLaks: I agree, it's way better when it comes to performance and is generally accepted as best practice, however, if he is looking for old browser support, the ones that do not support css pseudo classes, JS is the only way i think.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, you want to select a specific TD on a specific TR in your table.

If that's the case, collect the row index and add one to it (if you don't want to count the header).  Then selecting specific cells is easy.

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1; 
thisRow = "table tr:nth-child(" + row + ")";
thisCell = thisRow + " td:nth-child(N)";
```